# Should you be able to open in-page tabs in a new browser tab and retain the chosen tab state?

Tags: navigation, tabs, right-click

Our test team have just raised a query with me about in-page tab content and how that should behave should you choose to right-click and open in a new tab.

OK, it's a very fringe case here, but it did get me thinking. Currently most sites with in-page tabs will let you right-click the tab and open in new page, but it doesn't retain the chosen tab state - the new page shows with the first tab highlighted. (As an example see the tabs on this page: http://css-tricks.com/examples/OrganicTabs/ and try opening these tabs in a new browser tab.)

But I'm not sure if this is the ideal way to do things. If you visit a page with an in-page target anchor then you can right-click and open that in a new tab and it'll load with the page scrolled to that position. And this also has the benefit that you can copy the link and share it with others. But with the tabbed-content option you'll have to share it and then tell people *"Visit this page and click the 'Three' tab to read"*

So, what *should* happen here? Is it actually a problem that opening the tab content in a new browser tab doesn't retain the chosen tab state, or is that actually the correct behaviour?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQtRjL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If a user takes the effort to open the in-page tab in a new tab/window, you can assume they do so because they want to read the contents later on, but are currently reading the info on the screen right now.

My advice would be to open the new browser tab with the selecte in-page tab shown, while keeping the current page the way it is.